# Define and array in C++

Tags: c++, g++4.8

I have a question about this error from g++ on linux:

```
srcs/../incs/file.hpp:21:27: error: taking address of temporary array
 # define KEY_ESC_ (char[]){27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 srcs/main.cpp:91:16: note: in expansion of macro 'KEY_ESC_'
```

This is in a define as you can see. I don't understand why g++ say **taking address of temporary array**

It's more global than temporary...

This value is the key escape got from read

Any way ...

How can I solve it?

This code works on osx, but I need gross-compilation on linux ...

Thank you

Comment: You are using a C only header in a C++ source file by the looks of it.

Comment: `(char[]){27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}` is a *compound literal* -- not available in C++.

Comment: The error is coming from the code that uses the macro, could you show us that code? (also... **why** use `#define` in C++ and not a `const`?)

Comment: Please provide a **complete** example that produces the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a define statement, all instances of `KEY_ESC_` in your code will be literally replaced by `(char[]) {27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},` which will at that point in your code become a temporary variable.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have function like this: `void f(char** A)` so you pass `&KEY_ESC_`

`{27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}` is `const char` array.

by casting it to char[] you create a temporary variable.

the problem is that the method can save the address of the temporary and reuse it after it been released.

You can try to solve it by use a `const`:

```
const char KEY_ESC_[] = {27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

and call to method:

```
void f2(const char** A)
```

with:

```
f2(&KEY_ESC_);
```